# CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

Tags: c#, winforms, insert

> CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DataEntry
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"C:\USERS\ARUNKUMARREDDY\DOCUMENTS\Cons.accdb");

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dataSet1.callsheet' 
      // table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
      this.callsheetTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.callsheet);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      con.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Insert into Aplomb (ID,Vendor 
                           Name,Consultancy Name,Email ID,Phone No,Role,
                           Client,Job Location,Date)values('"+textBox1.Text+ "','" + 
                           textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + 
                           textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + 
                           textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "')con");
      sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
      MessageBox.Show("saved successfuly");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `..."')con");` Maybe you should look closely at your code before you post questions like this? Its pretty self explainatory, and the error is pretty apparent if you look at the syntax highlighting and the end of your query statement...

Comment: The SqlDataAdapter object does not have a constructor that takes a single string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: _Page of code critical hits you for 6 damage!_  Please don't post code without any explanation, particularly what the question is about.  _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 1):

Here some code it might help you

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
            // Open Connection
            conn.Open();

            // Define Sql Command
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SQL Query";
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            // Your Adapter, Editted you are insert not get Data Comment
            //SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            //adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But still you should check your code properly....